# How to align the bottom of two scaled images?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a layout containing two images and text.
I have scaled and centered them:

[image]

The last thing I'd like to do is to align the bottom of the two images as if they were both laying on the imaginary orange line in the pic. How can I do that? I'm playing with constraint layout but I am not able to find a solution.

The layout is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:id="@+id/home_card_card"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_top_between_cards_with_padding"
   app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/primary_bg"
   app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/card_corner_radius"
   app:cardElevation="@dimen/card_elevation_enabled"
   app:cardMaxElevation="@dimen/card_max_elevation"
   app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="true"
   app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/issue_body_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
            android:visibility="visible"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0"
            tools:visibility="visible">


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/issue_body"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:lineSpacingExtra="4dp"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                tools:text="This is the body of the issue" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/image_container"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:visibility="gone"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/issue_body"
                tools:visibility="visible">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/vox_left_container"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    tools:visibility="visible"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
                        android:id="@+id/vox_left"
                        android:layout_width="140dp"
                        android:layout_height="102dp"
                        android:scaleType="centerInside"
                        android:layout_margin="1dp"
                        android:visibility="gone"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:background="@color/transparent"
                        app:srcCompat="@drawable/device_vox_3_0"
                        tools:visibility="visible" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/vox_left_descr"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:textSize="18dp"
                        android:visibility="gone"
                        tools:visibility="visible"
                        tools:text="vox 30" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/vox_right_container"
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    tools:visibility="visible"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
                        android:id="@+id/vox_right"
                        android:layout_width="140dp"
                        android:layout_height="102dp"
                        android:scaleType="centerInside"
                        android:background="@color/transparent"
                        android:layout_margin="1dp"
                        app:srcCompat="@drawable/easybox_904"
                        android:visibility="gone"
                        tools:visibility="visible" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/vox_right_descr"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:textSize="18dp"
                        android:visibility="gone"
                        tools:visibility="visible"
                        tools:text="vox 30" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using ConstraintLayout properly. One of the points is that you don't have to use so many other types of layouts nested.

I quickly changed your code so it does what you want. But I recommend you to use a single constraint layout, and inside it, all your views without nesting them. As it is a simple layout the one you are doing.

I recommend you, watch a tutorial and try to learn more about how Constraint Layout works. Hope it helps!

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/home_card_card"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/colorPrimary"
app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
app:cardElevation="10dp"
app:cardMaxElevation="10dp"
app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="true"
app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/issue_body_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0"
        tools:visibility="visible">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/issue_body"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:lineSpacingExtra="4dp"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:text="This is the body of the issue" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/image_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:visibility="gone"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/issue_body"
            tools:visibility="visible">

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:id="@+id/vox_left_container"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:visibility="gone"
                tools:visibility="visible">

                <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
                    android:id="@+id/vox_left"
                    android:layout_width="140dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_margin="1dp"
                    android:background="@color/transparent"
                    android:scaleType="centerInside"
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/vox_left_descr"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/app_logo"
                    tools:visibility="visible" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/vox_left_descr"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:textSize="18dp"
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    tools:text="vox 30"
                    tools:visibility="visible" />

            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:id="@+id/vox_right_container"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:visibility="gone"
                tools:visibility="visible">

                <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
                    android:id="@+id/vox_right"
                    android:layout_width="140dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="1dp"
                    android:background="@color/transparent"
                    android:scaleType="centerInside"
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/vox_right_descr"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_audio"
                    tools:visibility="visible" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/vox_right_descr"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:textSize="18dp"
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    tools:text="vox 30"
                    tools:visibility="visible" />

            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```